# How to select one by one particular string in word vba script?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need selection particular content each paragraph in ms word 2013. I try to select content using by vba script..

```
Sub RepalaceStrong()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "<Strong"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Extend
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "</Strong>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
End Sub
```

But i tried this code, i can't select one by one text.

**Input:**

```
In general, a vector field is a function whose domain is a set of points in  <Strong> a vector field is </Strong> a vector field is <Strong>function</Strong> whose domain is a set of points 

>In general, a vector field is a function whose <Strong>domain</Strong> is a set of points
```

Is it possible to select one by one all strong elements...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct font formatting in your find operation (note the `.Font.Bold = True` part below):

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
```

Then, of course, it depends what you want to do with the bold text. Currently the code above just configures the `Find` object to search for bold text.

Answer (score 0):

It's not **strong** you're looking for, it's `Font.Bold`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FindBold()
    Dim myDoc As Document
    Set myDoc = ThisDocument

    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundRange As Range
    Set searchRange = myDoc.Range(0, myDoc.Range.End)
    With searchRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Execute
        Do While .Found
            Set foundRange = searchRange
            foundRange.Select
            foundRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            MsgBox "Found bold text."
            .Execute
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My ans:

```
Sub RepalaceStrong()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "<Strong"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
  Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Extend

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "</Strong>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
End Sub
```

I got it ....